# Prevent curl from removing "../" from queried URL?

Tags: linux, wget, curl

> Prevent wget or curl from removing "../" from queried URL?

The following `wget` query using `../` to directory traverse:

`wget http://192.168.0.24:7002/../../../../../mydir/myfile.txt`

results in the effective query with `../` removed from the URL:

```
--2018-08-16 10:22:53--  http://192.168.0.24:7002/mydir/myfile.txt
Connecting to 192.168.0.24:7002... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

How can I force `wget` (or `curl`) to keep the original URL verbatim?

Answer (score 2):

For curl try

```
 curl --path-as-is
```

> --path-as-is
>
> Tell curl to not handle sequences of /../ or /./ in the given URL
> path. Normally curl will squash or merge them according to standards
> but with this option set you tell it not to do that.
>
> Added in 7.42.0.

See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)